# Double-ended queue in h5py

Tags: python, deque, h5py

In my project I use python's deque as a limited buffer. The problem is a lack of RAM. That's why I'm looking for a solution and one option is to store the buffer on HDD.

I'm wondering if it is possible to enable limited deque in h5py's datasets.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: `h5py` presents `HDF5` groups as Python dictionaries, and datasets as `numpy` arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj What do you mean? If I understand correctly, groups are kind of folders and datasets are actually what I need.

Comment: Do you know anything about `numpy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/faq.html#appending-data-to-a-dataset) datasets do not even support appending

> The short response is that h5py is NumPy-like, not database-like.
>   Unlike the HDF5 packet-table interface (and PyTables), there is no
>   concept of appending rows.

So I myself have implemented the desired behaviour:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

class H5Buffer():
    def __init__(self, array_shape, maxlen, dtype):
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        self.current_idx = 0

        self.file = h5py.File("buffer.hdf5", "w")
        self.buffer =  self.file.create_dataset('buffer', (0,)+array_shape, maxshape=(maxlen,)+array_shape, dtype=dtype)        

    def append(self, array):
        '''
        array is numpy array with the shape of array_shape
        '''
        add_size = array.shape[0]
        if self.buffer.shape[0]<self.maxlen:
            self._resize(self.buffer.shape[0], add_size)

        add_idx = add_size
        end_idx = self.current_idx + add_idx

        if end_idx >= self.maxlen:
            add_idx-= end_idx - self.maxlen
            end_idx = self.maxlen

        self.buffer[self.current_idx:end_idx] = array[:add_idx]

        self.current_idx = end_idx
        if self.current_idx == self.maxlen:
            self.current_idx = 0
        if add_idx != add_size:
            self.append(array[add_idx:])

    def _resize(self, current_size, add_size):
        new_size = current_size + add_size
        if new_size > self.maxlen:
            new_size = self.maxlen
        self.buffer.resize(new_size, axis=0)

    def sample(self, start_idx, end_idx):
        return self.buffer[start_idx:end_idx]

    def length(self):
        return len(self.actions)

    def close(self):
        if self.file:
            self.file.close()
        self.file = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()
```